# How to change width of control when bootstrap is used

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, twitter-bootstrap

I have MVC app. and I am using bootstrap for CSS.
Now, I want to use text area in the view with width around 500px.

I have this code

```
 @Html.TextArea("Comment", "", 5, 200, new { @class = "Comment-" + @ViewBag.EId })
```

Now, in boot strap TextArea width is 206px, now I want to change the width of the textArea 
in this view only.  I dont want to change values in CSS.

How to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Html.TextArea(
    "Comment", 
    "", 
    5, 
    200, 
    new { 
        @class = "Comment-" + @ViewBag.EId, 
        style = "width: 500px" 
    }
)
```